# Python: Kivy window resize causes crash

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="test")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

When I try to resize it in a specific way, it crashes with this exit code

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have thought about 2 reasons why this could have happened.

**First case**

The first would be that you didnt have sdl2 dependancies for kivy before installing it. If you had pygame installed, there's a chance that it was used instead of sdl2. Since pygame uses SDL1 it may cause the problem. Doing this should fix it :

```
pip uninstall kivy

pip install kivy-deps.sdl2

pip install kivy
```

I dont think you have to uninstall pygame before reinstalling kivy but if it is not working then give it a try. For reference, here is the topic where I have found about a similar problem :

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/4326

**Second case**

In this case I suppose that your computer is calculating a lot of heavy stuff when the window is resized because of what you designed in it. Resizing in real time is indeed not the best idea. You can delay it and change the size only when ready. I have found this idea here if you want to check :

https://blog.kivy.org/2019/07/a-delayed-resize-layout-in-kivy/